# dart await on constructor

Tags: dart, future

What pattern should I use in this example to load and process some data. As `value` returns a value, it's not acceptable to have `d` as a Future. How can I get the constructor to wait until `load` has completed before continuing?

```
void main() {
    var data = new Data(); // load data
    print(data.value()); // data.d is still null
}

class Data {
    String d;
    Data() {
        load();
    }

    Future<void> load() async {
        d = await fn(); // some expensive function (e.g. loading a database)
    }

    String value() {
        return d;
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you call the load function from main

Comment: Are you sure that it's blocking? I'm trying it in my code now but it seems like it still has "d" as null when I run the second method.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You cannot make a constructor asynchronous.
An asynchronous function needs to return a `Future`, and a constructor needs to return an instance of the class itself. Unless the class *is* a future, the constructor cannot be asynchronous (and even then, it's not really the same thing, and you can't use `async`/`await`).

So, if your class needs asynchronous set-up, you should provide the user with a *static factory method* instead of a constructor. I'd usually hide the constructor then.

```
class Data {
  String _d;
  Data._();
  static Future<Data> create() async {
    var data = Data._();
    await data._load();
    return data;
  }
  Future<void> _load() async {
    _d = await fn(); 
  }
  String get value => _d;
}
```

As an alternative design, I wouldn't even put the load method on the class, just do the operation in the static factory method:

```
class Data {
  String _d;
  Data._(this._d);
  static Future<Data> create() async => Data._(await fn());
  String get value => _d;
}
```

Obviously other constraints might require that `load` has access to the object.

Comment: That first method looks really concise and is probably exactly what I'm looking for. Syntax wise, is Data._() just an empty constructor that we're using to prevent it being called elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, `Data._();` is just an empty *private* constructor, so nobody else can create instances of `Data` without also calling `load`. If we didn't write it, a default public constructor would be added.

Comment: @lrn could you help me on this link? `https://stackoverflow.com/q/56512200/1830228` thanks

Comment: I thought working with statics was a no-go and should be avoided if possible

Comment: Static functions (top-level or inside classes/mixins/extensions) are perfectly fine to use. It's a design question when to use one or the other, when to make a function static instead of a constructor or an extension method, but there are definitely use-cases where it's the right choice. An asynchronous factory function is definitely a good candidate.