# Dart using getter method to get private field value from class

Tags: dart

in this below class I have a private constructor with `getter`, unfortunately, I cant use this getter as `userDao` from outside of class, I get this error:

> Instance member 'userDao' can't be accessed using static access.

```
class MydbModel {
  UserDao _userDao;

  MydbModel._(this._userDao);
  static Future<MydbModel> create() async => MydbModel._(await fn());

  static fn() {
    MyDatabase myDatabase = MyDatabase();
    myDatabase.initialDatabase();
    return myDatabase.getUserDao();
  }

  UserDao get userDao=>_userDao;
}
```

for example:

```
final UserDao userDao = MydbModel.userDao;
```

this implementation means i use `await` on this constructor without create new instance from that to use and define this codes:

```
MyDatabase myDatabase = MyDatabase();
myDatabase.initialDatabase();
return myDatabase.getUserDao();
```

for example:

```
class MyDatabase {
  AppDatabase db;
  UserDao userDao;

  Future<void> initialDatabase() async {
    db = await $FloorAppDatabase.databaseBuilder('flutter_database.db').build();
  }

  UserDao getUserDao() {
    return db.userDao;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```dart
final UserDao userDao = MydbModel.userDao;
```

You're trying to access an *instance* getter through the *class*.  Either your getter and the private member need to be `static` or your need to construct an instance of `MydbModel` first.

Comment: ok, thats right. but i need to create constructor to avoid using await in outside of that, i pasted some codes to implementation on post to using them in ScopeModel with singletone instanse

Comment: you can see, my MyDatabase class

Comment: @DolDurma Your question title is "Dart using getter method to get private field value from class".  It sounds like you're actually asking about something different.  If your issue is about how to have a getter that depends on an asynchronous initializer, that's up to you. Either you have to make that getter asynchronous too (and wait for initialization to complete) or you define how the getter should fail if it's called too early (e.g. return null or throw an exception).